# C# User input Password log in session

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm trying to create a text-based password log-in for a class project. Unfortunately, it's C#, not python. So I make it so if the user gets it wrong it says incorrect but if they get it correct it says correct.The problem I am having is that I can't loop/retry it when I get it incorrect. Does anyone have suggestions or answers to this? (I have the example code below)

Thanks!

```
    using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int Password = 1234;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the password in order to enter");
         Password = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Password == 1234)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
            Console.WriteLine("Access Granted");
        } 
        else 
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
            Console.WriteLine("Access Denied");
            Console.WriteLine("Try again...");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The solution is to add a loop

Comment: If it were Python, what would you do?

Comment: I can make it with visual but cant make it text base

Comment: After you define `Password`, define another variable.  `bool isCorrect = false;`.  Then wrap all the rest of the code in a while loop:  while (!isCorrect) {...}.  Then in your `if` clause, when they enter the correct password, set `isCorrect = true;`.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a While loop and break when the password matches. Something like this:

```
int correctPassword = 1234;

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the password in order to enter: ");
    string? informedPassword = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
    if (informedPassword == correctPassword.ToString())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access granted!");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access denied!");
        Console.WriteLine("Try again...");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for what loop to use. I was using another loop a few minutes ago and it didnt go great

Comment: Sure, no problem! I used to work with Python and the transition for C# is a bit messy, since is a strong typed language (exactly opposite of Python). With time though, you get used. ;)